# How to add virtual attributes on the fly with strong parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

I have this controller:

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    if @current_account.update_attributes(account_params)
      redirect_to :dashboard
    end
  end

  def account_params
    params.require(:account).permit(:company, users_attributes: [:name, phone_attributes: [:number]])
  end
end
```

as you can see, i have 2 levels of nested attributes, the issue is I used to add a virtual attribute before using strong parameters like this:

```
def create
  @phone = @current_account.users.phone.requires_us_format = true
  ...
end
```

How to achieve this using both nested attributes and strong parameters?

Comment: and simply add `phone_attributes: [:number, :requires_us_format]` doesn't work for you? AFAIK `strong_parameters` only slice and dice your params and doesn't really refer back to how you define your model in anyway. https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb

Comment: @j03w but how to add `:require_us_format` to the params manually, it doesn't work for me as it returns `undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass` when i do `params[:account][:users_attributes][0][:phone_attributes][:require_us_format] = true`

Comment: Try to set requires_us_format on you before_save function on Phone model.

Comment: I only want to add the attribute on certain controllers

Comment: `params[:account][:users_attributes][0][:phone_attributes][0][:require_us_format]`? but from your error `params[:account][:users_attributes][0][:phone_attributes]` is `nil` though so make sure you actually have `phone_attributes` created on your params